# JS : conditionally playing sound with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I've got an array with 16 false booleans inside.

```
var arr = [];
for(let i=0;i<15;i++){
    arr.push(false);
}
```

I'm setting booleans [0] [4] [8] [12] to true.

```
arr[0]=true;
arr[4]=true;
arr[8]=true;
arr[12]=true;
```

And I also got a function playSound that creates and plays sound using WebAudio API.

```
function playSound(){
var oscillator = audio.createOscillator();

oscillator.type = 'sine';
oscillator.frequency.value = 440;
oscillator.connect(audio.destination);
oscillator.start(audio.currentTime);
oscillator.stop(audio.currentTime+0.5);
}
```

I want my "play" function to check if it is true in the given index of the array every 500 ms, and if it is then to play the sound with the playSound function.

```
var index = 0;

function play(){
    setInterval(function() {
    if(arr[index]===true){
        playSound;
        index++ % arr.length; ;
    }   
},500)}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What's wrong?

Comment: Where do you call `play()` ? **Edit** : also, `playSound` is the function. You forgot to add the parenthesis to call it

Comment: You aren't calling `playSound()`

Comment: On a side note, `index++ % arr.length` not incrementing the `index` variable. You need to change it to `index = (index + 1 )% arr.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people have mentioned forgetting the parenthesis `()` when calling `playSound`...

However, you're also only incrementing the `index` variable when `arr[index]===true`, which is probably not what you want. Consider your initial setup:

- `arr` looks something like this: `[true, false, false, false, true, ...]`
- `index` is set to `0`

When your function `play()` gets called, the interval gets going, so every 500 ms it runs. The first time it runs, it checks `arr[index]===true` (again, `index` starts at `0`). `arr[0]` is `true`, so the condition passes, so `playSound()` is called and `index` is incremented to 1.

On the next cycle, `arr[index]===true` is checked again, but this time `index` is `1` and `arr[1]` is `false`, so the condition does not pass AND `index` does not increment. So from now on, 500 ms will go by, the same condition `arr[index]===true` will be called, but `index` will never increment (since the `index++` line inside the `if-condition`).

So your issues seem to be:

1. `playSound` needs to be called with parenthesis -> `playSound()`
2. `index++` needs to be placed right after the `if-statement` inside the `setInterval` function like this:

Change your `play` function to look like this:

```
function play() {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (arr[index]===true) {
            playSound();
        }
        index++ % arr.length;
    }, 500)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = 0;

function play(){
    setInterval(function() {
    if(arr[index]===true){
        playSound();
        index++ ;
    }   
},500)}
```

I think you have forgotten the parenthesis `()` to call the method.